# Stacking unbalanced data in R data frame

Tags: r

I have arrays of data that will be combined (stacked) in a data frame for analysis. However, there is data missing for some individuals. I do not know the full list of variables in advance so aiming for a flexible solution to stack this data.

Example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
names(a) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
b <- c(1,1,1,1)
names(b) <- c("C","F","G","H")
c <- c(2,2,2)
names(c) <- c("A","D","H")
```

Desired result:

```
result <- data.frame(rbind(
                    c(1,2,3,4,5,6, NA, NA),
                    c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1 , 1),
                    c(2, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2) ) )

names(result) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H") 
result
```

When the fourth row of data comes in, ideally, it should simply be added to the existing variables where applicable, show `NA` where it has missings, and add new variables to the data frame if they do not exist yet. One can probably write some complicated (slow) for loop but there has to be a function/package that allows for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option using base R which doesn't require conversion to data.frame:

```
n <- unique(c(names(a), names(b), names(c)))
m <- t(sapply(list(a, b, c), function(x) x[match(n, names(x))]))
colnames(m) <- n
```

The result is:

```
print(m)
#      A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
#[1,]  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA
#[2,] NA NA  1 NA NA  1  1  1
#[3,]  2 NA NA  2 NA NA NA  2
```

If desired, you can then convert to `data.frame` using `as.data.frame(m)`.

---

Or, if you put your vectors in a list first, it would be:

```
l <- list(a, b, c)
n <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, names)))
m <- t(sapply(l, function(x) x[match(n, names(x))]))
colnames(m) <- n
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is simple, elegant, and helped me the most for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

you could try this

```
df.list = list(data.frame(a, ind = names(a)),
               data.frame(b, ind = names(b)),
               data.frame(c, ind = names(c)))

out = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'ind', all = T), df.list)

result = setNames(data.frame(t(out[,-1])), out$ind)

#   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
#a  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA
#b NA NA  1 NA NA  1  1  1
#c  2 NA NA  2 NA NA NA  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another base R option to consider if you're just dealing with named numeric vectors. The obvious difference here is `0` instead of `NA`, but you should be able to replace those too, if needed:

```
vec <- c(a, b, c)
rows <- rep(1:3, lengths(list(a, b, c)))
xtabs(vec ~ rows + names(vec))
#     names(vec)
# rows A B C D E F G H
#    1 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0
#    2 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
#    3 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 2
```

---

Here it is as a function:

```
myFun <- function(...) {
  lst <- list(...)
  vec <- unlist(unname(lst))
  rows <- rep(seq_len(length(lst)), lengths(lst))
  xtabs(vec ~ rows + names(vec))
}

myFun(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also you the `dplyr` package and the function `bind_rows` but you need to turn you vectors to `data.frame` first

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
names(a) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
b <- c(1,1,1,1)
names(b) <- c("C","F","G","H")
c <- c(2,2,2)
names(c) <- c("A","D","H")

### Dataframe with one row and vector name as column name
a <- as.data.frame(t(a))
b <- as.data.frame(t(b))
c <- as.data.frame(t(c))
## str(a)
## 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ A: num 1
##  $ B: num 2
##  $ C: num 3
##  $ D: num 4
##  $ E: num 5
##  $ F: num 6

bind_rows(a, b, c) ### or bind_rows(list(a, b, c))
##       A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
##   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
## 1     1     2     3     4     5     6    NA    NA
## 2    NA    NA     1    NA    NA     1     1     1
## 3     2    NA    NA     2    NA    NA    NA     2
```

Comment: This worked fine, thanks! However, in my application it broke down when I had a data frame with 1 TRUE/FALSE logic variable.